# Why is wizarding technology so far behind muggles?

Tags: harry-potter

In Harry Potter, Dudley has a Playstation, but wizards are still using quills instead of pens(and candles instead of electricity in Hogwarts). Is there any reason wizards don't use more recent technology?

Comment: Might want to check [this](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/a/16961/82345) answer out.

Answer (score 0):

Well, if you have magic you can ensure that the old-fashioned tools work just as well as the modern ones, so that there is no need to change.

And schools are notoriously conservative in such matters. Look how long it took muggle ones to accept the ball-point pen.