# Why Do Harry Potter Wizards Let Muggles Die Of Cancer Etc?

Tags: harry-potter

They are able to cure basically anything. And yet, they allow millions of Muggles (including children) to die painfully of cancer and other nasty diseases.

Why?

Comment: Wizards can do a lot of things, but I don't believe there's any canon indication that they can cure cancer.

Comment: @F1Krazy - Actually they can cure any mundane disease

Comment: Any proof wizards can cure cancer? Cancer isn't as mundane.

Comment: @BernardtheBear - Mundane as in **non-magical**; "*I decided that, broadly speaking, wizards would have the power to correct or override ‘mundane’ nature, but not ‘magical’ nature. Therefore, a wizard could catch anything a Muggle might catch, but he could cure all of it;*" - https://www.pottermore.com/writing-by-jk-rowling/illness-and-disability

Comment: Not Opinion Based. Any question that has a canon answer is automatically not opinion-based, and this clearly has a canon answer.

Comment: @TheAsh I don't think the "why" has never been addressed, hence why this might be POB. Of course the simple answer is "because it would break the international statute of secrecy"...

Comment: Are First World Countries Obscenely Selfish For Letting Other People Die Of Malaria Etc?

Comment: @TheAsh I'm sorry but I think it is POB, the title is "Are Harry Potter Wizards Obscenely Selfish" and the body is very much not a neutral question. If we edit the question into a neutral question such as "Why did wizards not intervene to help Muggles with health care &c." then I think this old question pretty much covers it: https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/14087/why-is-the-magical-world-kept-hidden-from-the-muggle-world

Comment: Hmmm.  In [Elizier Yudowsky's take on HP,](http://www.hpmor.com/) doing so would literally result in the end of the world, but I don't think the reasoning holds up in the original canon.

Comment: @ConradBennishJr - Yes.

Comment: @Valorum well said

Answer (score 13, accepted):

This is directly addressed in the opening of Harry Potter and the Philosopher's Stone.

> “But what does a Ministry of Magic do?”
>
> “Well, **their main job is to keep it from the Muggles that there’s
> still witches an’ wizards up an’ down the country.”**
>
> “Why?”
>
> “Why? Blimey, Harry, **everyone’d be wantin’ magic solutions to their
> problems. Nah, we’re best left alone.”**

So yes, it would appear that the wizarding world is *callously indifferent* to the plight of Muggles or at least recognises that if they provide magical help, it might expose their world and make them into a resource to be exploited.

Comment: It's odd that they don't see this as an opportunity to become obscenely rich.

Comment: What bugs me is that apparently wizards don't care about the environment either, even though everyone, even wizards, would benefit if they used magic to clean it up. I'm picturing wizard recycling shops where they just continuously transfigure garbage into something useful.

Comment: @MissMonicaE - Honestly I don't think the worldbuilding in HP holds up that well once you start to prod and poke at it.

Comment: Wizards in HP are not the most caring type. They still hold house elves slave and see themselves above over humanoid creatures. Their prison system was basically torture. It was quite clear in the book that wizardkind aren't nobody's angel.

Comment: @BernardtheBear - You might also want to add "[widespread use of date-rape drugs](http://harrypotter.wikia.com/wiki/Love_Potion)" to that list

Comment: RESOLVED: Wizards are jerks.

Comment: @Bernard The Bear What do you think Professor Minerva McGonagall would say if this question was put to her?

Comment: Umm... how about the point behind the International Statute of Secrecy: avoid being exterminated and/or exploited by the muggles, against whom the wizards are not sure they could win a war. Ron's point isn't necessarily flippant apathy, but a matter of free survival.

Comment: @Valorum Of course! One of the few potions/other miscellaneous items from the Harry Potter world that I would recognize immediately!

Comment: Does the International Statute of Secrecy possibly have anything to do with it? I think actually yes. Even if some wizards and witches have anti-Muggle sentiments it’s unfair and more so unrealistic to judge them on that when the statute is in place. Oh and seems I am not the only one to think of it. Sorry but it has more to do with the statute than anything else and any suggestion to the contrary is unrealistic post statute. Doesn’t mean they all care but it’s a moot point.

Comment: Jk Rowling used garden world building rather then planned world building, hence why there are so many inconsistencies in her books