# Outside Hogwarts, wouldn't it have been beneficial to use Muggle-technology as well as Magic?

Tags: harry-potter

Yes Muggle-techonology doesn't work at Hogwarts, but outside the castle, it sure would have helped Potter, Ron and Hermione at many instances, isn't it? Well,

Using the telephone to call Ron when he left for Bill and Fleur's?
Using the internet to look up the daily news, search about Horcruxes?
Using satellite TV to broadcast Potterwatch?
Using mobile phone to text, tweet updates among the anti-Voldemort movement?
Using motion sensors, motion alarms to help detect movements around the tent at night?

And so on.

Comment: Related [Why don't muggle-born wizards use Muggle technology to fight Death Eaters?](http://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/2611/why-dont-muggle-born-wizards-use-muggle-technology-to-fight-death-eaters)

Comment: I don't think there'd be much on Horcruxes on the *muggle* internet.

Comment: @Kevin Well, there is now!

Comment: @DJClayworth, Kevin - comment exchange of the week

Comment: From where did you find that Muggle-technology doesn't work at Hogwarts..

Comment: Remember that the events of the books played between 1991 and 1997. The internet wasn't so accessible at that time, especially not for a fugitive hiding in a forest.  And you can't just buy a motion alarm that distinguishes normal outside movements like the wind moving trees from hostile stuff like wizards sneakily moving around.  Such a motion sensor would be magic.

Comment: @SachinShekhar - relevant quotes are in the answers to Q linked by Jeremy

Comment: @SachinShekhar You mean you haven't read *Hogwarts: A History*?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Wizards:

1. Don't KNOW how to use even the most basic Muggle technology. Even the supposed expert (Mr Weasley) didn't know how to use the phone.
2. Don't - as a rule - have ACCESS to Muggle technology (or for that matter, Muggle money to buy it). Hermione may be different here.
3. Treat Muggle technology with complete disdain as 100% inferior to magic. Remember, they are mentally almost completely stuck in pre-1800s century.

   Example - they think that Wizarding moving photos are all that and Muggle still photos are lamez. Apparently nobody graduated to LCD displaying a short video off a flash card. etc...).

And yeah, if you think about it logically, main reason is out-of-universe - the entire premise of the books will be broken if you introduce guns, satphones, flashbang grenades, Arduino-based custom built sensor setups and UAVs with smart bombs.

Comment: Again, an LCD gadget displaying a short video off a flash card was nonexistant or very expensive in 1997.

Comment: @b_jonas - Fine, moving slide projectors (not sure what they are offifically called). They cost peanuts in 1980s. Also, Hermione's parents are **dentists**. Money is not an concern for her.

Comment: I'm not sure your second point is correct or valid. We know that Gringotts exchanges Muggle currency for Wizarding currency, so I don't think it's too big a stretch to assume they would do the reverse exchange too. We also know that Wizards do, on occasion, shop in Muggle shops. Access isn't an issue to those with the desire to obtain Muggle technology, it's the ignorance and disdain as you mentioned in your other two points, that prevents them from obtaining it.

Comment: @AnthonyGrist - we don't know if the reserve holdings have limits. They may only exchange small sums. Good point though