# What Would Have Happened If Voldemort Had Chosen Redemption?

Tags: harry-potter, voldemort

I'm not sure if my memory serves me correctly, but I recall that at the end of *Deathly Hallows*, before Voldemort and Harry fire their final spells at one another, the latter gives the former a last shot at redemption. My question is: **What if Voldemort had accepted that?**

His reasons could have been many, especially if he realised that the Elder Wand was not loyal to him. Even so, what would have the magical community done to him? I understand that Dementors are pretty much universally condemned following Voldemort's downfall, but perhaps Voldemort is the one person most deserving of a Dementor's Kiss. However, what's the point in redemption if you just get what remains of your soul sucked out of you?

I'm just curious as to how the world would have reacted to a Voldemort who, after all of the pain and suffering he had caused, surrendered at the final battle. After all, doesn't Voldemort fear death more than anything?

Your thoughts please gang.

Comment: Asking us to speculate how other characters in the universe may or may not have reacted is purely asking for discussion, making this off-topic. I'm sure people would be happy to talk about this in chat though.

Comment: Grindelwald was secured...

Comment: Related: https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/17678/what-would-voldemort-have-done-had-he-won?rq=1

Answer (score 0):

Offering Voldemort another way than fighting is retorical at best. Harry's task and intention were never to imprison Voldemort. That (theoretically) could be accomplished without destroying his Horcruxes. Surely, Horcruxes are dangerous by themselves, the entire HP2 is based on that. Still, the walking, talking and killing Voldemort should be given priority over finding and destroying hidden objects. Finding and destroying Horcruxes was always meant to lead up to killing Voldemort, nothing else.

There definetly was no way back for him into the wizarding community and it would be quite dangerous to exile him. Who would take him anyways? And on the other hand, locking him up for the rest of time would be very dangerous as well. Just imagine him getting his hand on a wand. He would be free in an instant and everything would start over.

Voldemort is so incredibly cunning and powerful, that the people would never feel safe as long has he is alive. He had to be removed permanently, but even for wizards the world is too small to simply put him somewhere else. He came back before and nobody would believe there is a prison secure enough to hold Voldemort. At least they would have killed him, maybe even subjected him to the Dementor's kiss. Probably the latter so that his empty body can be shown to the public as to reasure everybody that it is truly over.

Comment: Voldemort lost his body once. Public doesn't know nothing about Horcruxes.

Comment: which spawns the question: what happens to your soul wenn you have horcruxes and suffer the dementors kiss ... lets see if we already have that here ...

Comment: Yes, but no: I mean *shown to the public as to reassure* (not about kiss). It seems like a bad idea because it is inhuman. But main problem it is False. Empty body has nothing to do with Voldemort dead. In which case Harry would tell the truth because he ... well... must not tell lies!... Anyway, he always makes clear up stuff about Voldemort so people cannot be manipulated.