# Was Voldemort britain-only?

Tags: harry-potter, voldemort

If I remember correctly,Voldemorts ultimate goal was that wizards would be purified so that true bloods could rule the world of all "lesser creatures".
He had many sympathisants and wizards follow him out of fear,but every thing seemed to happen only in great britain.Is there any reason for this? Was he even known outside of GB? Were there any Death Eaters in other countries?

I know that he was born there and it makes sense to me that he would hide his horcruxes in places that mean something to him.But idealogies don't know borders and I always thought he was famous in the whole wizard world.

Comment: Hm,I've searched SE but did not get >anything< shown.Flagged myself.

Comment: Yet another possible duplicate is _[Did Voldemort plan to take over the entire world?](http://scifi.stackexchange.com/q/17678/19561)_, which itself might be a duplicate of _[What would Voldemort have done had he won?](http://scifi.stackexchange.com/q/17678/19561)_, based on their answers.