# Why was Voldemort's face white?

Tags: harry-potter, voldemort

In the *Deathly Hallows Part 2* when Harry was looking in the Pensieve he saw a lot of things but one of them was of voldemort killing Lily. His face was white. Why was it white if he didn't lose his body yet? He also didn't have a nose.

Comment: Maybe Harry saw it the way he thought he would.

Comment: Voldemort was already pretty inhuman even before his 'death' at the start of book 1. (I'm not sure why this is getting so many downvotes though.)

Comment: http://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/14866/when-did-tom-riddle-get-his-new-face

Comment: What makes you think his white face and non-nosiness was related to his losing his body? I don’t think there’s anything in the books to support that. When he comes back at the end of _Goblet of Fire_, he simply comes back looking like he did when he pseudo-died, i.e., exactly like on the night he killed Lily.

Comment: Could this question be a possible dupe of:
http://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/119618/what-does-voldemort-become-after-this-event-in-the-4th-book/119627#119627
or
http://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/14866/when-did-tom-riddle-get-his-new-face
or
http://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/17431/what-really-happened-to-the-nose-of-voldemort
?

Answer (score 10):

### Voldemort's appearance wasn't to do with losing his body - it was a result of creating Horcruxes.

Here's a memory that Harry views in Half Blood Prince. It shows Voldemort, a few years after leaving school, returning to Hogwarts to apply for the position of Defence Against The Dark Arts teacher.

> Harry let out a hastily stifled gasp. Voldemort had entered the room.
>   His features were not those Harry had seen emerge from the great stone
>   cauldron almost two years ago: They were not as snake-like, the eyes
>   were not yet scarlet, the face not yet masklike, and yet **he was no
>   longer handsome Tom Riddle. It was as though his features had been
>   burned and blurred; they were waxy and oddly distorted, and the whites
>   of the eyes now had a permanently bloody look, though the pupils were
>   not yet the slits that Harry knew they would become**.

At this point he has created some, but not all Horcuxes. His physical appearance degrades as he creates more.

Comment: If you could find a quote that backs up your last assessment, that would be a perfect answer. +1 anyway though.

Answer (score 4):

I don't have my copy of *Chamber of Secrets* anymore, but...

There's a part where someone (I think Dumbledore) explains that Voldemort was obsessed with not dying so he went through several dangerous "transformations" in his attempts. At the end of it all, he was no longer recognizable as Tom Riddle (and I presume this is when he lost his nose, so that probably didn't help matters).

When he failed to secure a teaching position at Hogwarts, he disappeared off the radar for a while, pursuing studies in the Dark arts, turning other objects into his Horcruxes, and going through said transformations. By the time he was the infamous Lord Voldemort, he didn't look much like his younger self. Voldemort probably wanted it that way, anyway. Everyone knew who Tom Riddle was, so someone could call him out on his blood status. But as this mysterious Lord Voldemort, only certain people knew that they were both one and the same.

If anyone could add the quote that would be awesome!