# Why we don't see guns in Harry Potter World?

Tags: harry-potter

They can shield bullets ? and a shot seems to be much stronger than a expelliarmus

Comment: welcome to the site! I believe your question though was already answered here: http://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/2611/why-dont-muggle-born-wizards-use-muggle-technology-to-fight-death-eaters

Comment: interesting,thanx for the link Justin :)