# If Voldemort intends for wizards to rule the muggles why the apparent hesitation to reveal Wizard superiority and the magical world to the Muggles

Tags: harry-potter

If Voldemort intends for wizards to rule the muggles does he also intend to reveal the magical world to the Muggles.

After Voldemort supporters takes over the Ministry of Magic and openly advocating that Purebloods should rule Muggles, he still has made no concentrated efforts to reveal the magical world to the muggles. No effort to finally reveal that Wizards are invincible and cannot be hurt or opposed by Muggles.

> Deathly Hallows The Wedding
>
> Then the Patronus’s 
>   mouth opened wide and it spoke in the loud, deep, slow voice of 
>   Kingsley Shacklebolt.
>
> ***“The Ministry has fallen.*** Scrimgeour is dead. They are coming.”

There is no one in the Ministry to oppose Voldemort from revealing Wizard Superiority. **The only thing stopping Voldemort is Voldemort himself.**

Is this acknowledgement on Voldemort’s part about the wisdom of **not revealing** the magical world of the Muggles, does Voldemort recognize that muggles can be dangerous in their own way.

I am reminded of this Mythbuster episode of Jaime and a gun against a horde of slow moving zombies, Jaime was still **taken down and disarmed.** Taken down by nothing more than slow walking brainless teeth.

Why the hesitation to reveal wizards as masters of Muggles and reveal the magical world?

> Deathly Hallows chapter Kreacher’s Tale
>
> But Master Regulus had proper pride; he knew what was due to the name of Black and the dignity of his pure blood. For years he talked of the Dark Lord, who was going to bring the wizards out of hiding to rule the Muggles and the Muggle-borns . . .”

In Great Britain alone http://www.express.co.uk/news/uk/260925/One-baby-born-every-40-seconds-in-Britain
One baby born every 40 seconds in Britain

For the rest of the world http://www.ecology.com/birth-death-rates/

- Four births each second of every day
- Nearly two people die each second

How many Muggles does Voldemort’s minions have to kill in a day, everyday 24/7 just to give Great Britain **zero population growth?**

I’ll let Voldemort do the math.

Comment: I think it was more a matter of not caring about the muggle world and needing to secure control over the wizards world.

Comment: Actually not exactly a duplicate, from Deathly Hallows chapter Kreacher's Tale "But Master Regulus had proper pride; he knew what was due to the name of Black and the dignity of his pure blood. For years he talked of the Dark Lord, who was going to bring the wizards out of hiding to rule the Muggles and the Muggle-borns . . ." But Voldermort is not delivering on the promise of wizards coming out of hiding to rule Muggles, even after his minions have full control of the Ministry. There is nobody in the Ministry to stop them - so why the hesitation with the Muggle world?

Comment: To be fair, it's Rowling we're talking about here, not Tolkien.. I don't think it's very well thought through. Consider Voldemort had openly shown himself to the world, MAYBE even taken control of GB.. You think Voldemort can survive a military attack ? Maybe a smaller one, but then the world would realize the danger.. I know this thought is not fun to think about in the magic universe but if you want to consider the possibility, revealing himself and magic to the world would've been his end. And a pretty quick one too. It's all just big talk, he needs the hiding aspect for his plan

Comment: Outright domination of muggles was just something to motivate his followers and a noble goal to show others so that he could justify his actions. Given the muggle vs wizard population difference I doubt he would really want to reveal himself. Moreover, as Lupin mentioned, revealing himself to even just the wizarding population would have incited a rebellion; things were relatively calmer during the last book because Voldemort remained in the shadows. Suddenly declaring domination over muggles, at least during the period of the last book, would have changed that.

Comment: Because Rowling has stated the same thing as many other writers. A gun beats a wand, an apache beats a dragon. Anytime.

Comment: http://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/2611/why-dont-muggle-born-wizards-use-muggle-technology-to-fight-death-eaters

Comment: "How many Muggles does Voldemort's minions have to kill in a day, everyday 24/7 just to give Great Britain zero population growth?" You’ve taken this firmly out of the world of fantasy and into population statistics. If that’s what you really want to know, take it to Math.se instead.

Comment: It was intended as rhetorical :)

Comment: You really lost me at zombie Mythbusters and ZPG.