# In Harry Potter book 7, why didn't the Order flee Britain after Harry turned seventeen?

Tags: harry-potter

Wouldn't it have been better for the Order to just flee Britain as soon as Harry turns seventeen, since I don't think anyone in the Order knows that Harry is hunting Horcruxes anyway?

Comment: ... because then they could help no-one but themselves?  This is a bit like asking why people don't leave their homes when some other country invades, instead of heading up the local resistance.  They don't because it's home.

Comment: The whole point of the Order was having an organised rebellion against Voldemort; why would they leave?

Answer (score 23):

#### Running away isn't the Order's style, nor would it have helped in the long run.

The whole point of the Order of the Phoenix is that **they're not the people who accept Voldemort's rule**: they're the ones who fight against him, who risk their lives for something worth doing. Fleeing the country to escape Voldemort doesn't fit their MO. They're the kind of people who stay and fight to the bitter end for what's right. Running away smacks of cowardice, which just isn't their style. Without them, who would have continued the fight? Who would have protected the Muggles and Muggle-borns of Britain from the Death Eater tyranny?

Plus, if they had fled the country, Voldemort would have had all the power and no serious opposition. After consolidating his hold on Britain, **he would surely have moved to conquer the rest of Europe and the world**. By fleeing, the Order would only have been putting off the inevitable - and by the time he had Britain more firmly under his thumb and was ready to move on to other countries, Voldemort would have been even *more* powerful, and they would have had even less of a chance of stopping him. Staying in Britain was their best, albeit slim, chance of defeating him: to catch him while his rise to power was still recent and not yet consolidated.

Comment: The muggles would have protected themselves. Once you begin searching for where the wizards are, Hogwarts would stand out like a sore thumb because it can't be mapped. Where could they be hiding hmmm? How about this gaping hole in the map! It will be bloody on both sides, but in the end the wizards cannot win.

Comment: @Joshua Now THAT's a [whole other issue](http://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/2611/why-dont-muggle-born-wizards-use-muggle-technology-to-fight-death-eaters). Muggle vs wizard combat is Just Not Done in HP, [however little sense that might make](http://www.dorkly.com/post/76324/why-muggles-in-harry-potter-dont-make-any-sense).

Comment: @Joshua I'm assuming that the magic behind making a place Unplottable is more than just leaving a hole in the map, or else it wouldn't be a very effective method of hiding things. Muggles would have noticed ages ago that, for example, all their Ordnance Survey maps of Scotland had this weird gap in them; after a few expeditions wandered back out of that area with missing memories and a vague sense of disorientation, there would be a military cordon and a team of scientists trying to identify this strange phenomenon.

Comment: @anaximander: now that's a Harry Potter book I'd read happily!

Comment: @anaximander: That's all very good until the GPS era.

Comment: @Joshua I presume GPS has the same issue. I don't picture Unplottable as being simply the inability to draw that part of the map; I imagine it working like your eye's blind spot, invisibly filling in the gap, or else by making the terrain seem subtly non-Euclidean and "folding" the Unplottable section out, so that if you walk around the edge of the Hogwarts defences, the disorienting Muggle-repelling charms and the Unplottable-ness combine to make it seem like you've traveled how far your Muggle maps say you should have, and arrived exactly where you expected to.