# Bullets vs Wizards

Tags: harry-potter

Would a magician in a harry potter universe be able to shield/block bullets fired from a muggle like pistol?

Example: James Bond vs. Harry Potter

Comment: http://harrypotter.wikia.com/wiki/Shield_Charm

Comment: http://harrypotter.wikia.com/wiki/Office_for_the_Detection_and_Confiscation_of_Counterfeit_Defensive_Spells_and_Protective_Objects

Comment: James Bond is an alcoholic geriatric. Harry Potter is a Messaianic superwizard. No contest.

Comment: Related, maaaaaybe dupe: [Why don't muggle-born wizards use Muggle technology to fight Death Eaters?](http://scifi.stackexchange.com/q/2611/21267)

Comment: @Mooz I disagree. The answers there address primarily *why* there are no guns in HP, not how wizards would fare against them.

Comment: @Mooz, I agree with Gallifreyan. The duplicate answer doesn't discuss if a Wizard could protect themselves against muggle weapons

Comment: @Gallifreyan Yupp, which is why I said `maaaaaybe dupe` :)

Answer (score 2):

Presumably yes, if properly prepared.

A wizard caught unawares would be just as vulnerable to a bullet as anyone else.  However, we don't have any evidence that spells would be useless against guns-- and some evidence that wizards aren't too concerned about them.  In *Prisoner of Azkaban*, the *Daily Prophet* tells the wizard community that Muggles have been told Sirius Black is armed with a gun, and describes a gun as

> "(a sort of metal wand Muggles use to kill each other)"

The lack of any further description indicates (to me) that a gun is no more a threat to a wizard than a sword, or a poisonous snake.

Comment: A [sword](http://harrypotter.wikia.com/wiki/Sword_of_Gryffindor) or a [poisonous snake](http://harrypotter.wikia.com/wiki/Nagini), eh?

Comment: Yes, exactly. :-)