# Did Gandalf have a secret plan?

Tags: tolkiens-legendarium, the-lord-of-the-rings, gandalf

I've checked [this question](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/2333/why-didnt-gandalf-or-frodo-fly-to-mount-doom) out, and Keen offers a great explanation for the seeming plot hole, but my question is a little different.

After reading [this reddit post](https://www.reddit.com/r/FanTheories/comments/130it2/lord_of_the_rings_a_theory_about_the_eagle_plot/), I'm really curious whether evidence/hints of this secret plan appear in either the books of the films.

## The Secret Plan

I've summarised the theory below, see the link above for the unabridged version

> Gandalf secretly planned on taking the fellowship to where the eagles live and having the eagles fly them to Mordor. The eagles lived on the other side of the Misty Mountains but all the routes for crossing them were too dangerous and difficult, and Gandalf (along with his secret plan) ends up falling down a chasm in a battle with the Balrog. Just before falling with the Balrog he tries to surreptitiously tell them the secret plan but was too subtle and they didn't understand. When he came back as Gandalf the White he had forgotten many things, including the plan to meet the eagles.

The most alluring evidence is Gandalf the Grey's last words:

> **Fly you fools!**

which could possible be interpreted as a hint to the Fellowship (**necessary because Sauron has ears everywhere and preserving the element of surprise is vital**)

### So, any idea if there's more supporting evidence/hints to support this theory?

Comment: I reckon he could have just said **Ride the giant eagles to Mordor** really fast, if that's actually what he was trying to say..

Comment: I seriously doubt that Tolkien would have had a character say "fly" meaning "travel (on a flying creature) through the air".

Comment: I like this guess at a "secret plan". I think Draft may be right though, instead of "fly you fools" he could have said "Fly on the eagles you fools." if that's what he wanted to say.

Comment: I agree with Draft too. Plus @MattGutting is spot on, Tolkien would have found a better way for Gandalf to say it, if that's what he meant.

Comment: The idea is that he can't tell them explicitly because Sauron has ears everywhere and there's a need to preserve the element of surprise.

Comment: @Huey I don't think Sauron had hidden microphones on The Fellowship's clothes. He couldn't hear their conversations. Otherwise, why weren't they talking in code the whole time?

Comment: To be fair, they were being shot at by goblins as they fled the mines.

Comment: -1 from me. This sounds like someone's really flimsy attempt to justify a fan theory.

Comment: It's actually very clear what Tolkien means by "Fly, you fools!" Earlier on, just as the Balrog is arriving, Gandalf tells the rest of the Fellowship "Fly! This is a foe beyond any of you. I must hold the narrow way. Fly!" That is "Get going; flee from this powerful enemy and let me combat it!" not "Ride on a winged animal!"

Comment: In addition to @MattGutting's comments about the use of the word "Fly" prior to Gandalf falling, the next paragraph reads "Even as Aragorn and Boromir came flying back, the rest of the bridge cracked and fell".

Answer (score 8):

Isn't it the

> To flee, to escape (from).

meaning he is using? Like in "*Fly, my lord! The enemy are upon us!*"

Second meaning of the second etymology on [wiktionary](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/fly).

Comment: Also the "Fools" part. Standing their ground to help Gandalf and fight the balrog made them fools. Proceeding to Gondor on foot as per the plan made in Rivendell wouldn't warrant a "You Fools"

Comment: In the OP theory, I suppose Gandalf was saying "Stop fighting and wasting time, you *fools*, just go out and *fly* with giant eagles". But it can't be understood with the "*Fly, you fools!*" sentence. Especially with the knowledge of the fellowship of the Gandalf friends.

Comment: See my comment on the question. Before his fight with the Balrog Gandalf says, "Fly! This is a foe beyond any of you. I must hold the narrow way. Fly!" Here he's definitely **not** saying anything about transportation via winged animals. Given this statement, I think it's unreasonable to believe that he is talking about air transportation in his "Fly, you fools!" statement.

Comment: @MattGutting we are all convinced about that since start about it. ^^