# Who is "He that flies" in Lord of the Rings?

Tags: tolkiens-legendarium, the-lord-of-the-rings

In the chapter 7 of book three in *Lord of the Rings* titled "Helm's Deep", the scout says the following.

> ‘It is very great,’ said the scout. ‘He that flies counts every foeman twice, yet I have spoken to stouthearted men, and I do not doubt that the main strength of the enemy is many times as great as all that we have here.

Who is "He that flies"?  I also can't understand the meaning of the whole passage, so please explain it all.

Comment: "He who flies" is a way of describing someone who is fleeing a battle. It doesn't refer to a particular character.

Comment: @user888379 "Flies" as in "fly you fools."

Comment: @Lorendiac, I guessed it might be Gandalf since the scout reported his being sighted before with Shadowfax. Anyways... I got my answer, thanks everyone!!

Comment: Comments were getting way off-topic; [this meta post](https://scifi.meta.stackexchange.com/q/11626/31394) continued the discussion, but TL;DR is **this question is on-topic here**.

Comment: I just wanted to say that the last edit in this question, which I re-edited just now, was incorrect. Book 3 in LotR doesn't mean _The Return of the King_, it means book 3. There are 6 books in the epic novel of LotR, published in 3 parts, which he who edited should've known before editing the question. Thanks for noticing the question and it's an honest mistake, but it's a mistake nonetheless. I hope I have explained myself.

Comment: If you’re going to be pedantic there are 7 books in the “epic novel” that makes up _The Lord of the Rings_. However since that isn’t exactly common knowledge it makes much more sense to use the volume titles, in this case _The Two Towers_.

Answer (score 154, accepted):

It means "the accounts of people who are scared enough to flee the battle are unreliable because they tend to overestimate the size of the enemy force, but I have spoken to brave men and they confirm our enemies are indeed numerous".

Here "fly" means [to run away](https://www.etymonline.com/word/fly), the same as when Gandalf utters the famous "fly, you fools!".

Comment: Or for another fairly well-known use, Emerson's Brahma: "They reckon ill who leave me out; When me they fly, I am the wings; " (https://www.poetryfoundation.org/poems/45868/brahma-56d225936127b )

Comment: There we have it: actually the famous Gandalf quote has always been misinterpreted! What he really meant there was, he'd suddenly come up with a [much better plan of how they should go about destroying the ring](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/2333/why-didnt-gandalf-or-frodo-fly-to-mount-doom/). Too bad he didn't have time to explain anymore...

Comment: @leftaroundabout, I'm guessing you're just joking around. But I wanted to express **my opinion** that that theory about flying over Mordor is not practical in Middle Earth at that time.

Comment: @klaus You only say that because Mordor has who knows how many bowmen, siege machines, its own air force, an all-seeing air detection system and thick clouds of pollution that would choke an eagle in a few minutes. Frankly, with that kind of defeatist mind, we'd never had won WWI in four months of glorious infantry charges.

Comment: @Eth Obviously, you're forgetting that you need to [blindfold the eagle and have Aragorn distract Sauron](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=1yqVD0swvWU) in order to pull this off. "Well, that was incredibly easy." "Yes, it was." "Can you imagine if we had walked the entire way?"

Comment: @Eth, well, I haven't even thought along those lines. I just thought that Eagles doesn't like to be bothered with other people's meddling. Even when Gwaihir rescued Gandalf from Orthanc, he only bore Gandalf to safety, not `to the ends of the earth`. They possess bigger, or similar, power than Gandalf, and given that the Ring can be destructive in the hand of a powerful being, it's not practical to involve a sovereign species of such great power. This was my line of thought. I didn't even think about the WWII war tactics and stuff, I'll leave that to you.

Comment: @klaus Indeed, in the books, this is [what is going on](https://www.tor.com/2016/12/21/tolkien-eagles-manwes-special-ops/). The Eagle-drop is generally about the film, where little is known about the Eagles' motivations, and it is easier to assume they are Generic Good Guys. But even then, it simply wouldn't have worked, had the Eagles being willing to try.

Comment: @Eth, oh! I thought you were criticizing my point. Sorry, my bad.